# Google App Engine Access Cloud Datastore from Different Project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have been trying to find a solution to accessing a datastore in one project from a different google app engine project. I went through the tutorial on accessing a datastore from a different project's compute engine, however, this is not what I am looking for. What is required here is accessing a datastore on one project from a different app engine project. Has anyone done this successfully? Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

As @Patrice says, this is possible by using the [Remote API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) (or [for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi)), which lets you access different App Engine services from any other application, as stated in the documentation.

For a more specific information on how to access the Datastore remotely with the Remote API, please take a look at this [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) from the documentation that explains step by step all the procedure.

Please, take into account that if your Google account is configured to use [2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744), you will need an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) that authorizes the app to access your account resources.

Comment: are there any performance or other costs to this approach? or is it basically the same as using a default GAE configuration?

Comment: Yes there are: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/remoteapi#limitations_and_best_practices

Answer (score 1):

there is actually an API that lets you make calls to App Engine services from anywhere, even from another App, as long as the credentials are ok, it's called the "[remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi)"