# Query an existing Google Cloud Datastore from Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Entity with ~50k rows in Google Cloud Datastore, the stand alone not GAE. I am starting development with GAE and would like to query this existing datastore without having to import it to GAE. I have been unable to find a way to connect to an existing datastore Kind.

Basic code altered from Hello World and other guides im trying to get working as a POC.

```
import webapp2
import json
import time
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Product(ndb.Model):
type = ndb.StringProperty()

@classmethod
def query_product(cls):
    return ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Product where name >= :a LIMIT 5 ")

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'

    query = Product.query_product()

    self.response.write(query)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Returned Errors are

```
TypeError: Model Product has no property named 'name'
```

Seems obvious that its trying to use a GAE datastore with the kind Product instead of my existing Datastore with Product already defined, But I cant find how to make that connection.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one Google Cloud Datastore. App Engine does not have a datastore of its own - it works with the same Google Cloud Datastore.

All entities in the Datastore are stored for a particular *project*. If you are trying to access data from a different project, you will not be able to see it without going through special authentication.

Comment: Andrei, thanks for clarifying that for me. The App I am working with is in the same project as my Datastore. I will look through the documentation again to try and find my issue.

Comment: Go to your Google Cloud Platform console (https://console.cloud.google.com) and check if you see your data (under "Datastore > Entities").

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too certain what it is you're trying to accomplish when you say that you `would like to query this existing datastore without having to import it to GAE`. I'm  guessing that you have project A with the datastore with 50k rows, and you're starting project B. And you want to access the project A datastore from project B. If this is the case, and if you're trying to access the datastore from a different project, then maybe [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392175) that mentions [remote api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code. I was pretty close at the time I made this original post but the reason I was getting no data back was because I was running my App locally. As soon as I actually deployed my code to App Engine it pulled from Datastore no problem.

```
import webapp2
import json
import time
from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query import Cursor
from google.appengine.ext import ndb



class Product(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'


    query = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Product where name >= 'a' LIMIT 5 ")
    output = query.fetch()

    #query = Product.query(Product.name == 'zubo - pre-owned - nintendo ds')
    #query = Product.query()
    #output = query.fetch(10)
    self.response.write(output)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```